# longpress to scroll :mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have scollable area , i want to user long press and then scroll to scroll that area.

is there any way to detect mouse / touch event movement after long press so that i may do above functionality

see : http://liveweave.com/ggfAdD

please help i am stucked up
belwo i code of longpress, what top add code to make it work where user long press and move up / down

```
  (function($) {
    $.fn.longpress = function(longCallback, shortCallback, duration) {
        if (typeof duration === "undefined") {
            duration = 500;
        }

        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);

            // to keep track of how long something was pressed
            var mouse_down_time;
            var timeout;

            // mousedown or touchstart callback
            function mousedown_callback(e) {
                mouse_down_time = new Date().getTime();
                var context = $(this);

                // set a timeout to call the longpress callback when time elapses
                timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    if (typeof longCallback === "function") {
                        longCallback.call(context, e);
                    } else {
                        $.error('Callback required for long press. You provided: ' + typeof longCallback);
                    }
                }, duration);
            }

            // mouseup or touchend callback
            function mouseup_callback(e) {
                var press_time = new Date().getTime() - mouse_down_time;
                if (press_time < duration) {
                    // cancel the timeout
                    clearTimeout(timeout);

                    // call the shortCallback if provided
                    if (typeof shortCallback === "function") {
                        shortCallback.call($(this), e);
                    } else if (typeof shortCallback === "undefined") {
                        ;
                    } else {
                        $.error('Optional callback for short press should be a function.');
                    }
                }
            }

            // cancel long press event if the finger or mouse was moved
            function move_callback(e) {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            }

            // Browser Support
            $this.on('mousedown', mousedown_callback);
            $this.on('mouseup', mouseup_callback);
            $this.on('mousemove', move_callback);

            // Mobile Support
            $this.on('touchstart', mousedown_callback);
            $this.on('touchend', mouseup_callback);
            $this.on('touchmove', move_callback);
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```